# Restrinct access only for Admin User

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to deny access to all users that aren't admin to my user's list.

My route is : `http://localhost/exchangeIt/web/backend/llistaUsuaris.`

So I tried to deny it in the security.yml file.

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_TRANSLATOR: ROLE_TRANS

 access_control:

- { path: ^/backend/llistaUsuaris/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But if i join with a common user and copy paste the url i can access even if im not admin user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any other security check ? If yes - show us your code, if not - concider following

In your Backend-Controller you can use either `@Security` Annotation for whole Controller Class or/and for a certain Method. [More Info](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html)

or you could make use of `$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', $user, 'You shall not pass');` methon in your Controller for a specific Method  [More info](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-new-shortcut-methods-for-controllers)

`@Security` is **quick and easy**, but `denyAccessUnlessGranted()` gives your much more controll

Comment: @Pillow glad to help ;)